Listen for sink-added in splitmuxsink gstreamer-rs
I want to create chunked MPEG-TS segments from video file and send them to datastore without touching the filesystem.
So I've created a pipeline with splitmuxsink where I set muxer-factory to mpegtsmux and sink to app sink.
I want to switch from using sink to sink-factory in order to be able to use async-finalize .
How can i listen to sink-added event using gstreamer-rs ?
